# SSAS tabular DISTINCTCOUNTNOBLANK equivalent

Tags: visual-studio, dax, ssas, ssas-tabular

I have the data below in SSAS tabular import from sql server

```
create table #Data (ID int,Names varchar(50))
insert into #Data values
(1,'one'),(2,NULL),(3,'two'),(4,'one'),
(5,NULL),(6,NULL),(7,'two'),(8,'three'),
(9,'one'),(10,NULL),(11,'two'),(12,'one'),
(13,NULL),(14,NULL),(15,'two'),(16,'three')
 select * from #Data
 drop table #Data
```

I want to count distinct value as a measure excluding blank from Names columns
I wrote the below DAX it is given error

```
Total = CALCULATE(
                    DISTINCTCOUNTNOBLANK(Data[Names]),
                  filter(data,Data[ID]>10 
                   )
                   )
```

How can I write the DAX in SSAS Tabular in Visual studio

Thanks

Comment: Can't replicate an error. What's the error message?

Comment: @Olly it shows error in the measure no message. it shows error sign

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this measure. The NOT(ISBLANK()) part is the is the [equivalent of DISTINCTCOUNTNOBLANK](https://dax.guide/distinctcountnoblank/).

```
Total := CALCULATE(
 DISTINCTCOUNT(Data[Names]),
 Data[ID]>10,
 NOT(ISBLANK(Data[Names]))
)
```